# Footfullcite and shrink

Tags: beamer

I have a large equation on my slide, and I shrink the slide. Unfortunately this causes the footnote to move down, only the first line of the footnote is visible. Without an actual footnote you can see the horizontal line moving downwards compared to the page without shrink. Is there a way to make the footnote fully visible when I use shrink?

```
\documentclass[unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[english, magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}{
\usebeamerfont{footline}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
\hspace{1em}
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\hspace{1em}
}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\frame[shrink=20]{\frametitle{Title~\footfullcite{mandelbrot68}}
FBM
}

\frame{\frametitle{Title2~\footfullcite{mandelbrot68}}
FBM2
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could simply shrink the equation and not the whole slide:

```
\documentclass[unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[english, magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}{
\usebeamerfont{footline}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
\hspace{1em}
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\hspace{1em}
}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\frame[shrink=20]{\frametitle{Title~\footfullcite{mandelbrot68}}
FBM
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title~\footfullcite{mandelbrot68}}
 \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
     text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}

\frame{\frametitle{Title2~\footfullcite{mandelbrot68}}
FBM2
}

\end{document}
```